# Blocking websites with Screen Time

Tags: security, privacy, internet, parental-controls, screen-time

I'm trying to block distracting websites using Screen Time.

It seems I have to select the 'Limit Adult Websites' option and then add a restricted URL. I've tried to restrict YouTube but the settings seem to have no effect?

I can still visit YouTube just fine?

[image]

Comment: did you enable the passcode